# Issues with release:perform but not with release:prepare

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I think I am misunderstanding something import with the maven-release-plugin. I am able to do `mvn release:prepare` successfully but `mvn release:perform` always fails.

Maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 11:31:09-0600)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.6.0_25, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

My POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.animals</groupId>
<artifactId>cats</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>cats</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:hg:https://repo.org/repo</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:hg:https://repo.org/repo</developerConnection>
</scm>

<build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
              <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
        </configuration>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
<repository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <url>https://repo.org/repo</url>
    <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
</repository>
</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

The error that I am getting when I run `mvn release:perform` is:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plug
in:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project cats: Failed to deploy artifacts: Coul
d not find artifact com.animals:cats:jar:0.0.1 in repo (https://my-repo-url)
```

I am really at a loss as to why this is happening. I have tried setting up a separate repository just for `release:perform` but no luck, I have tried using the same repository for `release:prepare` and `release:perform`, I have tried omitting the `<distributionManagement/>` section. I have also tried changing the preparetion goals in the maven-release-plugin to be `clean install`. All of these are solutions that other stackoverflow users have found to be helpful but unfortunately they are not working in this case.

Is the problem in my pom.xml configuration, or perhaps something else? If there is any other information that you might need please let me know! I appreciate your time and help!

**EDIT:** This is a very simple project with no modules. 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is the version I have currently defined, and all other Maven goals seem to be working with no issue. I am not using any profile.

**EDIT** I have edited the question to include my entire POM.xml.

Comment: Do you have a multi module build? Have you defined a version like 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT before mvn release:prepare / mvn release:perform? Does your build work with mvn clean package etc. ? Do you need some profiles to be activated ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will update the question with the answers

Comment: Can you post the complete POM ?

Comment: Your SCM and distribution urls are the same - is that intentional?

Comment: It was intentional for the purposes of figuring out how to work this plugin. Is that allowed, or is that my issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The problem was indeed with my repositories and not the pom.xml.

Comment: What was the problem with your repos? I'm experiencing a similar issue and I believe it's my repos but can't quite figure out the issue. `mvn [compile|package]` works fine but `release:perform` is failing to find deps (looking in wrong repo)

Answer (score 0):

Put this to the configuration of the release plugin: `<goals>install</goals>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems, that you need `mvn release:stage` instead of `release:perform`